# AG-grid charts unable to process 60,000 data points

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When I am building the chart with less data points, the chart is displaying correctly. However, when the datapoint exceeds 60,000 it gives an error.

```
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely exceeding the available memory space.

Frankly, I'd be extremely surprised if the end-user can distinguish the difference in chart containing 60K points and one containing 30K points, or even many fewer, like perhaps several hundred?

I would experiment with graphing, say, every other data point and see how that works out, then maybe go further, and stop reducing the number of points used when it becomes noticable.